# Repeated Reality Revisions Inherent Bonus To Attribute Material Component Cost?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

In the text for [Reality Revision](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/r/reality-revision/) as follows:

> Grant a creature a +1 inherent bonus to an ability score. Two to five reality revisions manifested in immediate succession can grant a creature a +2 to +5 inherent bonus to an ability score. Inherent bonuses are instantaneous, so they cannot be negated or dispelled. An inherent bonus cannot exceed +5 for a single ability score. Inherent bonuses to a particular ability score do not stack; only the best one applies.

"Immediate succession" implies a grouping of multiple uses of Reality Revision into an overall event/experience of raising an ability score by +2 to +5.

Does this group the manifestations into a single chain, and if it does, is the cost of a $25K crystal only needed to launch the first Reality Revision of the chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Each manifestation consumes a crystal

The answer is in the power's description:

> Two to five reality revisions **manifested** in immediate succession
>
> (...)
>
> Manifesting reality revision requires channeling psionic power through specially-treated crystals similar to cognizance crystals that cost 25,000 gp. **The crystal is consumed in the manifestation** and becomes inert, unable to be used again and losing any value.

Each manifestation means you used the power once again (see [Manifesting a Power](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/TOC-Manifesting-Powers) in the psionic rules), similar to casting multiple spells in sucession, usually by spending one standard action per round (as per [Bend Reality](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/b/bend-reality)).

> Psionic characters and creatures manifest powers. Whether they cost power points when manifest by a psionic character, or are manifested as psi-like abilities, powers’ effects remain the same.
>
> The process of manifesting a power is akin to casting a spell, but with significant differences.

Comment: So therefore does "Immediate succession" imply that if one Reality Revision is manifested to grant a +1 to an ability score, and then several months down the track another Reality Revision is manifested to grant a +1 to an ability score they do NOT stack?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I believe this is supposed to parallel the Inherent bonus available to some Arcane spellcasters through [Wish](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wish/) so I'd expect the costs to be similar.